# Склонение имен существительных

Tags: склонение, недопустимая-метка

Что такое существительные с управляющими словами?

Answer (score 2):

Это слово, от которого зависит существительное, чаще всего глагол или другое существительное: писать (чем?) ручкой. Сумка для чего? Для книг. Управляющие слова требуют определенного падежа существительного. Это бывают числительные (два(кого?) брата), прилагательные (серый от чего? от пыли).

Answer (score 0):

Способ связи "управление".